# Is calling $find a relatively expensive operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am just wondering what the pros/cons would be between these two styles of coding:

```
var foo;
$(document).ready( function() {
    foo = $find(fooID);
});

function OnBarClicked()
{
    foo.doStuff();
    foo.doMoreStuff();
}
```

compared to

```
function OnBarClicked()
{
    $find(fooID).doStuff();
    $find(fooID).doMoreStuff();
}
```

I feel like there's probably a gotcha in the former, but I'm not aware of why there would be a gotcha. In addition, if there's any seek time for `$find()`.. is it more efficient to find all variables guaranteed to be 'found' 2+ times at the start, and then use the one instance?

EDIT: [$find description and usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx)

```
var radListBox1ID = "<%= RadListBox1.ClientID %>";
var radListBox = $find(radListBox1ID);
alert(radListBox.get_id()); //Alerts RadListBox1.ClientID
```

Comment: ...I assume by `$find` you mean `$`

Comment: ... is $find not normal? I have it literally everywhere in my code. Perhaps it is Telerik's jQuery extension that provides it... one moment.

Comment: Are you developing in ASP.NET? `$find` isn't part of jQuery core, but is it offered as part of ASP.NET Ajax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you for the reference. I edited the post tags to be more appropriate, and will add the reference to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're asking if querying the DOM once vs multiple (one per statement) with `$()`...

**Yes**, it is more **efficient** to use a single `$()` and store the result in a variable, rather than invoke jQuery at every statement **if you are using the element multiple times within the same scope**...

This is particularly useful in event handlers where you are referencing `this` as a jQuery object multiple times.

```
$('#element').click(function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(this);

    $clicked.doStuff();
    $clicked.doMoreStuff();
});
```

Comment: When you say 'within the same scope' does that mean that finding and assigning my variables globally, and then using them in local scope, would be bad practice? For what reasons? Is it just that the benefits are negligible compared to how messy it makes the code?

Comment: It is more a stylistic comment about what clean javascript looks like, **the more you can minimize scope pollution the better**

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you felt that there was a gotcha in the first example, and indeed, there is: You declare the `foo` variable in a local context that your `onBarClicked` function doesn't have access to. You'll get an undefined error if you try to use it. To fix that problem, declare `foo` in the global scope:

```
var foo;
$(document).ready(function () {
    foo = $(fooID);
});
```

When it comes to your actual question, the short answer is: **Yes. Running the search once and storing the result will be faster.**

But if you're only searching for an element by its ID, then in all honesty it probably won't make much of a difference. The times when it really matters are when you have a complicated selector that involves attribute selectors or pseudo-elements or descendant combinators or stuff. You'd definitely want to save that result instead of running it again and again and again.

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work as your would expect since foo won't be defined in `OnBarClicked`. `foo` gets set in the callback function once the document is ready.

Comment: Err, yeah. You're correct. One second, I will edit to reflect a proper declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this aproach:

```
$( function () {

    // get all the references (to the DOM elements) ASAP
    var header = $( '#header' )[0],
        nav = $( '#navigation' )[0],
        toolbar = $( '#toolbar' )[0];
        // etc.

    // now whenever you need to work with a referenced DOM element
    // just wrap it inside a jQuery object
    $( nav ).click( function () { ... });

});
```

Comment: You're calling $() twice for each element that way. What advantage does your code provide?

Comment: @Sonny You can do `$( nav )` as many times you want - that expression merely creates a jQuery instance based on the existing DOM reference (no performance penalty involved). What you *do* want to avoid is querying the same selector multiple times (like `$( '#navigation' )`). Unlike wrapping DOM references, selector queries do introduce performance penalties.